# PHP - json_decode как работать с таким JSON?

Tags: php, json, json-encode

Помогите разобраться . Есть JSON, но не могу понять что за структура и правильная ли она. А главное - как сделать по нему json_decode?
Мне нужно добавить в него еще 1 объект.

```
a:3:{i:0;a:1:{s:6:"status";s:1:"1";}i:1;a:1:{s:6:"status";s:1:"0";}i:2;a:1:{s:6:"status";s:1:"0";}}
```

Comment: Это не json . .

Comment: А что это есть понимание? Просто какая-то структура?

Comment: Это данные, сериализованные функцией [`serialize`](http://php.net/serialize). Десериализация производится, сооветственно, функцией [`unserialize`](http://php.net/unserialize).